# Moq an object with a nested property that doesn't have interface

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

We have the following code to test if it works:

```
Car car = await someService.CreateAsync(wheels);
List<string> urls = car.Input.Endpoints.Select(x => x.Url);
```

Now I'm trying to mock the car returned by someService in the first line to test the second line. I tried this:

```
var car = new Mock<Car>();
var carEndpoint = new CarEndpoint(url: "http://google.com");
car.Object.Input.Endpoints.Add(carEndpoint);

var someService = new Mock<ISomeService>();
someService.Setup(o => o.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<Wheels>())).ReturnsAsync(car.Object);

var myClass = new ClassToTest(someService.Object);
...
```

But it throws an error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: ....Endpoints
> Non-overridable members (here: Input.get_Endpoints) may not be used in
> setup / verification expressions.'

The problem is that Car is created by someService which I can't modify and neither Car nor Input implements any interface. How can I mock this in order to test the second line from the top?

```
List<string> urls = car.Input.Endpoints.Select(x => x.Url);
```

As requested, I'm leaving the Car class (simplified):

```
namespace X
{
    [JsonTransformation]
    public class Car : AnotherClass
    {
        public Car();
    
        public Car(CarInput input, string description, ...);

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "properties.description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "properties.input")]
        public CarInput Input { get; set; }
        
        ...
    }
}
```

It was proposed to create the object manually without Moq, doing so we had to write a lot of lines as, first because the second line is not the only property we are testing (remember this is a simplified scenario) and second we had to put new everywhere to create the structure needed for the nested properties. How can be this avoided giving that we can't modify the Car class nor it has an interface.

Comment: Post the `Car` class, please

Comment: 99% you really don't need to mock a car and simply creating one would work just fine... But indeed as @zaitsman said without actual example we can't help much.

Comment: The Car is an external class with a lot of properties that are external objects themselves, the Input is one of them and none implement interfaces. I will add the class nonetheless.

Comment: @zaitsman Alexei Done

Answer (score 2):

So given the listing of Car as more or less a POCO, why not just

```
var car = new Car();
var carEndpoint = new CarEndpoint(url: "http://google.com");
car.Input = new CarInput { Endpoints = new [] { carEndpoint } }; 
// or convert the above to list or whatever you have

var someService = new Mock<ISomeService>();
someService.Setup(o => o.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<Wheels>())).ReturnsAsync(car);

var myClass = new ClassToTest(someService.Object);
```

Comment: Isn't there a better alternative using Moq?

Comment: Define `better`. Creating a POCO directly is always better. Moq exists to create implementations of interfaces and abstract classes, not concrete models.

Comment: The [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) library can be a great way to create this data automatically as well, as it will auto-populate the desired object (`Car`, here) using reasonable defaults for both constructor injection and property injection.

This avoids the complaint that you would need to construct such a complicated object manually. I use it (and Moq) all the time.

Comment: @JeffDammeyer see, this is exactly the kind of stuff I would oppose in my project :) hence it is opinion based. Their readme says `It can create values of virtually any type without the need for you to explicitly define which values should be used`. This means that, for example, if their library starts to generate a different value for an `int` your tests may just start failing simply because you updated that library. This is opaque to the debugging devs and is difficult to read.

Comment: @zaitsman Well received, but keep in mind that this library is entirely customizable so that, in your example, you can define exactly how an `int` will be created as well, if indeed it matters for what you're testing.

And when it doesn't matter (for your test) how such a dependency is created, you leave it alone.

I just offer this library for dear question asker, since manual creation of POCOs for this test was a concern.